# Cannot access script base class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.core.script.template.ProjectScriptTemplate'

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin, gradle

While creating Gradle Project with default code, getting the error **"Cannot access script base class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.core.script.template.ProjectScriptTemplate'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"**. Able to build the project but the error is visible as red lines in build.gradle.kts file.

I'm new to Gradle and I'm trying to use Gradle with Kotlin. In Eclipse EE IDE, downloaded all the plugins and created basic Gradle project. Created the project with local installation of gradle. I didn't made any change to any file. I'm able to build the project but the build.gradle.kts file is filled with error  Not sure how It's building the project. It's annoying to see the errors and because of this error auto-correction and syntax checked also not working. Attached image for reference.

[Eclipse IDE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFXVQ.png)

Versions:

Eclipse: 2023-12 (4.30.0)

Java: JDK-17

Gradle: 8.4

Plugins:

1. Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0
2. Enhanced Kotlin For Eclipse
3. Kotlin Plugin For Eclipse 0.8.24